# ArrayList add/remove callback in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, callback

Is it possible to create a callback function ArrayList add/remove method.

ArrayList will contain image urls and I would like to run my code (update UI) as soon as I add/remove new element.

Comment: Why not just run your `add()` or `remove()` in a method of your class, then call whatever else you need to in that method? There is no listener for an `ArrayList`'s events, you'd have to extend it and make your own.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: I couldn't answer to your comment because you deleted the answer. What you call a cliche, I call a recommendation. And ArrayList will have at least three new methods in Java 8. Two of them (sort() and removeAll(Predicate)) will need to be overridden, breaking even more the List contract. SO the odds are 100%.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Encapsulate the list in your own object, and do whatever you want before or after adding an element into the list:

```
public class UrlContainer {

    private List<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>();

    public void add(String url) {
        doSomething();
        urls.add(url);
        doSomethingElse();
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: +1 This is exactly how I'd do it and leads to the least extraneous code.

Comment: Yes. And that's normal, since you want them to do something else than they do in ArrayList. Implement the minimal number of methods to implement what you need. Don't try to implement everything ArrayList can do, since you probably don't need everything.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a Decorator. You extend ArrayList but you also implement the interface, so you are basically masquerading as an instance, you are augmenting the core behavior, or decorating it.

[Decorator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Glazed Lists](http://www.glazedlists.com/). You can create an EventList and listen for the add/remove events.

(And yes, internally they use delegates...)